# Programmatically Check LTE capability on Android Device

Tags: android, lte

I want to check if the device my apk is running on has LTE capability.

Now, I have tried http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html 
but this only gives me information about current network type(GPRS/LTE). But i want to know if the phone has LTE capability at all, even if it is connected to GPRS at the moment.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Maybe you could do this by having a database of versions and whether or not they support LTE?

Comment: With over a 1000 android devices available, and new devices added to the list every week, this would be too painful to use. Not to mention, getting the Build.Id for each existing one is easier said than done. So, according to me, this idea of a database ain't practical. :(

Comment: It's pretty well established that this feature doesn't exist in Android APIs. So anyone who really, really wants it, has to look at other options. Yes, you're right that it would be a lot of work, and expensive, to provide such a database. But also bear in mind that you would only have to include in such a database, devices that do support LTE. Also, what is the market share of the leading device manufacturers? Maybe LTE devices from a few leading manufacturers would account for the vast majority of LTE devices currently in your target market.

Comment: The situation is constantly changing, and it depends on how important this requirement is, plus what degree of accuracy you would need.  I have looked at non-direct alternative ways of trying to estimate the network, such as IPv6 support or the existence of an EPS bearer, but haven't found anything reliable here either.

Answer (score 3):

It's not in the APIs so, officially the answer is no.
I reverse engineered the first LTE phone during the summer and didn't find any thing I could use

Maybe someone else was luckier ?